# Most elegant way to handle ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE when running Ansible via Docker?

Tags: docker, ansible, containers

I am working on containerizing the way we run Ansible playbooks as a part of our continuous integration pipeline. Today we have dedicated build servers with Ansible installed, but I would like to abstract it away with Docker. What I am trying to get my head around is how to handle the Ansible Vault secret when running from a container.

On the build servers we have a file containing the Vault secret as [described in the docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_vault.html) with the `ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE` environment file pointing to it. What is the most elegant way to handle this file in a Dockerfile to make it generic?

My current draft looks like this:

```
FROM ansible/ansible:ubuntu1604

ENV ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING false
ENV ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE ~/vault.txt

WORKDIR /var/AnsiblePlaybooks

RUN pip install \
    ansible \
    pywinrm  \
    pysphere \
    pyvmomi \
    kazoo

ENTRYPOINT ["ansible-playbook"]
CMD ["--version"]
```

I am planning to pass the playbooks in via something like a volume container and running it by overriding the `CMD` when running it. 
So my only case here is how to work with the `ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE` file? I could write it run-time from a "secret" variable like Docker or Kubernetes Secrets, but I am not sure how this can be done most elegantly.

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/groupon/ansible-silo

Answer (score 1):

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  ansible:
    image: myansibleimage
    environment:
      ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE: /vault/YOUR_VAULT_FILENAME
    volumes:
      - /path/on/host/of/vault/dir:/vault
```